# Inserting a phpmyadmin sql dump without phpymadmin

Tags: php, sql, insert

I'm moving a site that had access to phpmyadmin to one where I don't (not yet anyway). Is there a php script to import the generated .sql file into a database? The db is created and ready, just need to import the tables and records.

Comment: have a look at mysqli multi_query

Comment: Perhaps you can just ask your hosting provider to import the dump for you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

Upload your SQL file to the web space via FTP and execute a page with this code in it.

```
<?php
$file="path/to/file.sql";

$command = "mysql -u $dbuser --password='$dbpassword' --host='$sqlhost' $dbname < $file";
exec($command);
?>
```

Don't forget to set the variables for database name, username, and password. Also, make sure PHP has access to execute commands using the exec function.

Answer (score 1):

Why use php, why not use MySQL itself:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html

Comment: connect to your host via ssh (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) and run it from the command prompt (shell), or use the MySQL Workbench: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html

Comment: i am totally lost, especially in the mysql workbench...how can i use the SSH thing? does terminal (mac osx) work?

Comment: In my case so I can encapsulate the DB creation into the PHP code -- the PHP script first checks the table schema and if the tables are missing, it builds the DB [self installing].  This is a non-public implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Use SSH. Install PuTTy first. Ask your host the server IP, username and password for SSH server, and then do the work. Anyway, how do you think you are going to properly manage your tables and databases without phpmyadmin or any other alternative SQL client, eh? Ask your hosts to install them. Btw, looks like your host's at Antarctica or some other ancient place. I mean, come on man, a SQL client like phpMyAdmin is offered even in free subhosting.

Comment: yeah, learn how to use the Shell Command first, though. Install a virtual server on your PC and then learn how to use it properly, and then only use SSH.